# When to use these plain Te-Forms?

Tags: conjugations, て-form, imperatives

I've studied the use of a polite(?) te-form conjugation that is used to enumerate actions or for a request (adding `ください`). Examples would be `聞いて`, `死んで`.

But what about non-polite(?) te-form conjugations? `聞け`, `死ね`, when do you use them?  They rather seem imperative, as if the speaker were giving an order with an angry tone, but I believe that's actually the case of the `〜なさい` suffix.

Comment: "what about non-polite(?) **te-form** conjugations? 聞け, 死ね, when do you use them" >> ?? Sorry, are 聞け and 死ね te-form?

Comment: A "te-form" is a form ending in 〜て.  It isn't a general term for asking/telling people what to do.

Comment: The forms you're talking about are called imperatives, or 命令形.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's talk about the imperative in Japanese: an imperative is a way to give orders and/or commands. However, the form  of these utterances decides whether they are humble requests to barked orders.

You can find a quite complete reference [here](http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/grammar/requests)

In general you can use a number of forms:

- ます-stem+`なさい`: this is a polite yet firm request. It is often used to soften orders, between parents and child or boss/employee.

  > よく聞｛き｝きなさい！
- て-form+`ください` or noun+`ください`: This also a polite way of expressing a request, think of "Please do this". This is widely used, I hear it all the time in classrooms:

  > 座｛すわ｝ってください！
- The imperative form that is made from either turning the last syllable of a godan verb to the corresponding `e` pair or by adding `ろ` to the stem of a ichidan verb. This one is used for strong orders, such as those you give to your dog:

  > 走｛はし｝れ！ しっかりしろ！

There are other variations, but these are the main imperative forms. Note that the て-form is one imperative form among many others. Usage of those forms depends a lot on the context, mainly the current situation and relationship between the speakers.

An interesting example is `頑張｛がんば｝る`, to do one's best, to strive for perfection.

- 頑張りなさい would typically be used by soccer moms encouraging their children.
- 頑張ってください　would be used to encourage a co-worker.
- 頑張って　may be used by friends encouraging you
- 頑張れ　(often written ガンバレ) will be used by sports fan cheering on their favorite team/player.

Unfortunately there is no set rule, so it will take some time to recognize in which situation which form of imperative is to be used.

Comment: This is exactly the kind of explanation I was looking for, thank you very much. I didn't know what I was asking wasn't `Te-form` so that's pretty much what was blocking me. Also +1 for the furigana.

Answer (score 0):

Choco's right but being pedantic ;)

~て form is often used as a casual direct request/command. ドア開けて！早く飲んで！ Adding くれ！makes it very powerful, impatient, angry, desperate or comic.

~なさい is more how you would politely but strongly address/command/request a child or 'lower' person. You could also see it as one step down in formality from ください。

Like many things, tone, delivery and situation impart a lot of nuance and variety of application.

Comment: I think you've got the meaning for ～くれ wrong. It's just the auxiliary verb くれる "for me"

Comment: As in 　早くやってくれ！　？I'd call that a fairly powerful demand/command in spoken Japanese.

Comment: Certainly, but the power comes from the imperative form.