# What's the difference between やぬて and やぬる?

Tags: translation, word-choice

I was wondering what's the difference between the two. Google translate uses the same English translation for both, but I've seen different translations in animes, where やぬて (yamete) seems stronger. And google search also didn't yield and concrete answer. What's the difference between the two?

Comment: Please check the difference between ぬ and め. The correct spelling is やめて or やめる.

Comment: Welcome to the Japanese SE. The difference is the conjugation of the verb. Please do your own research before asking, and enjoy your stay!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When to use these plain Te-Forms?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/30564/when-to-use-these-plain-te-forms)

Comment: Also perhaps [Imperative form is rude...?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/38519).

Comment: @GuiImamura thanks. I did do my research prior to asking here. but based on the downvotes and the fact that I used ぬ in place of め, I gather I had used wrong search terms!

Comment: Out of curiousity, while it's entirely understandable to mistake the hiragana visually as a new learner, how did you manage to *input* it wrongly? Normal ways to input Japanese text (for Westerners) typically involve typing the romaji.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I used Gboard's built-in hiragana typing. didn't know till now that I could use latin characters. So thanks!

Comment: Also, could you by any chance have mistakenly swapped る and ろ? That would make a valid word with a completely different tone.

Comment: Oh, perhaps I'm too old-fashioned, then. I was only considering desktop computer input methods, not smartphones.

Comment: @GuiImamura yes... Oh my question has so many issues. I guess I'll leave it undeleted just in case a similar case happens with someone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

やめる is the dictionary form / base form of the verb ''to stop / to quit doing something''

やめて is the て form of やめる and when it stands alone it is used as a command: in this case meaning stop it.